# Comparing objects within the same array JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, csv

I'm trying to compare objects within the same array. I have a CSV file that contains some data in a delimited list. After the file is ingested I need to filter through it and print out the output to screen or console based on two conditions:

If for the same satelliteID there are three readings that are under the red low limit within a five minute interval.

If for the same satellite there are three thermostat readings that exceed the red high limit within a five minute interval.

I believe I can use array.filter and then array.map the to achieve the desired output but not sure where to go from here as far as looping through the array and comparing the objects.

Here is the desired result:

```
[
    {
        "satelliteId": 1000,
        "severity": "RED HIGH",
        "component": "TSTAT",
        "timestamp": "2018-01-01T23:01:38.001Z"
    },
    {
        "satelliteId": 1000,
        "severity": "RED LOW",
        "component": "BATT",
        "timestamp": "2018-01-01T23:01:09.521Z"
    }
]
```

Here is what the CSV file looks like:

```
timestamp|satelliteid|redhigh|yellowhigh|yellowlow|redlow|rawvalue|component
20180101 23:01:05.001|1001|101|98|25|20|99.9|TSTAT
20180101 23:01:09.521|1000|17|15|9|8|7.8|BATT
20180101 23:01:26.011|1001|101|98|25|20|99.8|TSTAT
20180101 23:01:38.001|1000|101|98|25|20|102.9|TSTAT
20180101 23:01:49.021|1000|101|98|25|20|87.9|TSTAT
20180101 23:02:09.014|1001|101|98|25|20|89.3|TSTAT
20180101 23:02:10.021|1001|101|98|25|20|89.4|TSTAT
20180101 23:02:11.302|1000|17|15|9|8|7.7|BATT
20180101 23:03:03.008|1000|101|98|25|20|102.7|TSTAT
20180101 23:03:05.009|1000|101|98|25|20|101.2|TSTAT
20180101 23:04:06.017|1001|101|98|25|20|89.9|TSTAT
20180101 23:04:11.531|1000|17|15|9|8|7.9|BATT
20180101 23:05:05.021|1001|101|98|25|20|89.9|TSTAT
20180101 23:05:07.421|1001|17|15|9|8|7.9|BATT
```

Here is the code that I have written to ingest the file and parse it.

```
const readFile = require("fs").readFile;
readFile("./data.csv", "utf-8", (err, data) => {
  //Store final results
  var result = [];

  //Split Each line in the CVS
  const lines = data.split("\n");

  //Assumes the first line in the csv is the header
  var headers = lines[0].split("|");

  //Create value pair
  for (var i = 1; i < lines.length; i++) {
    var obj = {};
    var currentline = lines[i].split("|");

    for (var j = 0; j < headers.length; j++) {
      obj[headers[j]] = currentline[j];
    }

    //Add objects to result array
    result.push(obj);
  }
  console.log(result);
});
```

This is what is logged to the console thus far after parsing the CSV file.

```
[
  {
    timestamp: '20180101 23:01:05.001',
    satelliteid: '1001',
    redhigh: '101',
    yellowhigh: '98',
    yellowlow: '25',
    redlow: '20',
    rawvalue: '99.9',
    component: 'TSTAT'
  },
  {
    timestamp: '20180101 23:01:09.521',
    satelliteid: '1000',
    redhigh: '17',
    yellowhigh: '15',
    yellowlow: '9',
    redlow: '8',
    rawvalue: '7.8',
    component: 'BATT'
  },
  {
    timestamp: '20180101 23:01:26.011',
    satelliteid: '1001',
    redhigh: '101',
    yellowhigh: '98',
    yellowlow: '25',
    redlow: '20',
    rawvalue: '99.8',
    component: 'TSTAT'
  },
  {
    timestamp: '20180101 23:01:38.001',
    satelliteid: '1000',
    redhigh: '101',
    yellowhigh: '98',
    yellowlow: '25',
    redlow: '20',
    rawvalue: '102.9',
    component: 'TSTAT'
  },
  {
    timestamp: '20180101 23:01:49.021',
    satelliteid: '1000',
    redhigh: '101',
    yellowhigh: '98',
    yellowlow: '25',
    redlow: '20',
    rawvalue: '87.9',
    component: 'TSTAT'
  },
  {
    timestamp: '20180101 23:02:09.014',
    satelliteid: '1001',
    redhigh: '101',
    yellowhigh: '98',
    yellowlow: '25',
    redlow: '20',
    rawvalue: '89.3',
    component: 'TSTAT'
  },
  {
    timestamp: '20180101 23:02:10.021',
    satelliteid: '1001',
    redhigh: '101',
    yellowhigh: '98',
    yellowlow: '25',
    redlow: '20',
    rawvalue: '89.4',
    component: 'TSTAT'
  },
  {
    timestamp: '20180101 23:02:11.302',
    satelliteid: '1000',
    redhigh: '17',
    yellowhigh: '15',
    yellowlow: '9',
    redlow: '8',
    rawvalue: '7.7',
    component: 'BATT'
  },
  {
    timestamp: '20180101 23:03:03.008',
    satelliteid: '1000',
    redhigh: '101',
    yellowhigh: '98',
    yellowlow: '25',
    redlow: '20',
    rawvalue: '102.7',
    component: 'TSTAT'
  },
  {
    timestamp: '20180101 23:03:05.009',
    satelliteid: '1000',
    redhigh: '101',
    yellowhigh: '98',
    yellowlow: '25',
    redlow: '20',
    rawvalue: '101.2',
    component: 'TSTAT'
  },
  {
    timestamp: '20180101 23:04:06.017',
    satelliteid: '1001',
    redhigh: '101',
    yellowhigh: '98',
    yellowlow: '25',
    redlow: '20',
    rawvalue: '89.9',
    component: 'TSTAT'
  },
  {
    timestamp: '20180101 23:04:11.531',
    satelliteid: '1000',
    redhigh: '17',
    yellowhigh: '15',
    yellowlow: '9',
    redlow: '8',
    rawvalue: '7.9',
    component: 'BATT'
  },
  {
    timestamp: '20180101 23:05:05.021',
    satelliteid: '1001',
    redhigh: '101',
    yellowhigh: '98',
    yellowlow: '25',
    redlow: '20',
    rawvalue: '89.9',
    component: 'TSTAT'
  },
  {
    timestamp: '20180101 23:05:07.421',
    satelliteid: '1001',
    redhigh: '17',
    yellowhigh: '15',
    yellowlow: '9',
    redlow: '8',
    rawvalue: '7.9',
    component: 'BATT'
  }
]
```

Comment: What is this 5 minutes interval? and I think redhigh or redlow is decided using rawvalue. correct?

Comment: Yes you use the rawvalue to determine whether it falls into the high or low so if I was to use filter I would probably go with result.filter(item => item.rawvalue > item.redlow) or something like that. The 5 minute interval involves comparing the timestamps to see if they fall within 5 minutes of eachother for the same ID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `reduce` along with `filter`.

```js
const arr = [ { timestamp: '20180101 23:01:05.001', satelliteid: '1001', redhigh: '101', yellowhigh: '98', yellowlow: '25', redlow: '20', rawvalue: '99.9', component: 'TSTAT' }, { timestamp: '20180101 23:01:09.521', satelliteid: '1000', redhigh: '17', yellowhigh: '15', yellowlow: '9', redlow: '8', rawvalue: '7.8', component: 'BATT' }, { timestamp: '20180101 23:01:26.011', satelliteid: '1001', redhigh: '101', yellowhigh: '98', yellowlow: '25', redlow: '20', rawvalue: '99.8', component: 'TSTAT' }, { timestamp: '20180101 23:01:38.001', satelliteid: '1000', redhigh: '101', yellowhigh: '98', yellowlow: '25', redlow: '20', rawvalue: '102.9', component: 'TSTAT' }, { timestamp: '20180101 23:01:49.021', satelliteid: '1000', redhigh: '101', yellowhigh: '98', yellowlow: '25', redlow: '20', rawvalue: '87.9', component: 'TSTAT' }, { timestamp: '20180101 23:02:09.014', satelliteid: '1001', redhigh: '101', yellowhigh: '98', yellowlow: '25', redlow: '20', rawvalue: '89.3', component: 'TSTAT' }, { timestamp: '20180101 23:02:10.021', satelliteid: '1001', redhigh: '101', yellowhigh: '98', yellowlow: '25', redlow: '20', rawvalue: '89.4', component: 'TSTAT' }, { timestamp: '20180101 23:02:11.302', satelliteid: '1000', redhigh: '17', yellowhigh: '15', yellowlow: '9', redlow: '8', rawvalue: '7.7', component: 'BATT' }, { timestamp: '20180101 23:03:03.008', satelliteid: '1000', redhigh: '101', yellowhigh: '98', yellowlow: '25', redlow: '20', rawvalue: '102.7', component: 'TSTAT' }, { timestamp: '20180101 23:03:05.009', satelliteid: '1000', redhigh: '101', yellowhigh: '98', yellowlow: '25', redlow: '20', rawvalue: '101.2', component: 'TSTAT' }, { timestamp: '20180101 23:04:06.017', satelliteid: '1001', redhigh: '101', yellowhigh: '98', yellowlow: '25', redlow: '20', rawvalue: '89.9', component: 'TSTAT' }, { timestamp: '20180101 23:04:11.531', satelliteid: '1000', redhigh: '17', yellowhigh: '15', yellowlow: '9', redlow: '8', rawvalue: '7.9', component: 'BATT' }, { timestamp: '20180101 23:05:05.021', satelliteid: '1001', redhigh: '101', yellowhigh: '98', yellowlow: '25', redlow: '20', rawvalue: '89.9', component: 'TSTAT' }, { timestamp: '20180101 23:05:07.421', satelliteid: '1001', redhigh: '17', yellowhigh: '15', yellowlow: '9', redlow: '8', rawvalue: '7.9', component: 'BATT' } ];
const res = arr.reduce((acc, {timestamp,satelliteid:satelliteId,redlow,redhigh,component})=>{
  const getDate = str => new Date(str.slice(0,4)+'-'+str.slice(4,6)+'-'+str.slice(6));
  const date = getDate(timestamp);
  let severity;
  if(arr.filter(obj=>+obj.rawvalue < +redlow && getDate(obj.timestamp) - date <= 5 * 60 * 1000).length >= 3){
    severity = 'RED LOW';
  } else if(arr.filter(obj=>+obj.rawvalue > +redhigh && getDate(obj.timestamp) - date <= 5 * 60 * 1000).length >= 3){
    severity = 'RED HIGH';
  }
  if(severity){
    acc.push({satelliteId,severity,component,timestamp});
  }
  return acc;
}, []);
console.log(res);
```